# include vs exclude relations - can't model former _properly_

Tags: alloy

Let's say,

- there are four unique objects A,B,C and D.
- There are also four unique boxes b1, b2, b3 and b4.
- Some objects out of the A,B,C,D set are put in box b1; entirely removed to return the object set to its previous A,B,C,D configuration; then put in box b2; removed and so on. until b4..In other words, we have four "recombination rounds"
- A box can hold as many objects as required, but
- There is a constraint: each of the objects will be missing exactly once from exactly one of the four recombination rounds That is, the rounds are going to be (order doesn't mater):
  ABC, ABD,ACD, BCD.

---

Ok, now - if I try to model that using a "skipround" relationship:

```
abstract sig Object {
  skipround: one Box
}
abstract sig Box {} 
one sig A,B,C,D extends Object {}
one sig b1, b2,b3, b4 extends Box {}
fact {
  all b:Box | one o:Object | o.skipround=b
}
run {} for 5
```

... and it works.
OTOH, if I model an "includedinround" relationship:

```
/// note the fact turnaround

abstract sig Object {
  includedinround: set Box
}{#includedinround = 3}
abstract sig Box {} 
one sig A,B,C,D extends Object {}
one sig b1, b2,b3, b4 extends Box {}
fact {
  all o:Object | one b:Box | o.includedinround != b 
}
run {} for 5
```

.... no instance found

what gives?

Answer (score 0):

I think your fact section should look like this:

```
fact {
    all o:Object | one b:Box | b not in o.includedinround
}
```

In your original fact, `b` is always a singleton set, i.e. it has exactly one element. But `o.includedinaround` has three elements. So `b` and `o.includedinaround` can never be equal. So `o.includedinround != b` is true for *every* b, not just *one* b and the fact can never be true. So no instance is found.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I just updated the model to follow your suggestion and it turned out, there are some Boxes with four Objects and some with as few as one. Not the intended outcome - my point is for each of the Objects to be excluded from a Box exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way that Alloy Analyzer interprets signatures' atoms and quantifies over them makes a little confusion. For the first model, once the fact statement quantifies over `Box`, Alloy knows there are exactly four distinct objects of `Box` in the universe. But in the second fact, the quantifier can have an infinite number of `Objects` atoms in the universe. Assuming `o1` and `o2` are two atoms of `Object`, then `includedinround` can be `{o1->b1,o1->b2,o1->b3,o1->b1,o2->o3->b3}`. Basically, the distinction between atoms does not imply the actual semantics of uniqueness that you might intend. These quantifiers are called unbound quantifiers.

In general, one solution for this issue is to write a predicate that guarantees the actual uniqueness of the composite signature like `Object`:

```
fact uniqe_fact{all disj o,o': Object | o.includedinround = o'.includedinround}
```

Now, `fact inclusion1_fact{all o:Object | one b:Box | b ! in o.includedinround}` would work; although, due to the constraint in the appended fact, there are four unique atoms of `Object` that makes `inclusion1_fact` unnecessary.

Another possible solution is quantifying over a bound entity, which is `Box`  in this case. The following fact also works since there are exactly four atoms of `Box` to be quantified on:

```
fact inclusion2_fact{all b:Box | one o: Object | (b + o.includedinround) = Box}
```